# How do I toggle an item (of seven) within a div without toggling items in another div with the same class name in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I toggle an item (of seven) within a div without toggling items in another div with the same class name in jQuery?

To make it more precise:
I have a grading system, which has different categories. I want the user to click on the grade within a certain category. The remaining aspects should toggle in. (or out, if the user wants to correct himself) Then the user moves on to the next category and picks the next aspect out of seven. How do I keep the already chosen aspects and not let them toggle in again, while the user clicks on the next one?

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div id="headline">
            <p>Überschrift: Inhaltliche Gestaltung - Wertung x4</p>
        </div>

            <div class="div_a">
                <div class="a" id="1">
                    <p>Keine Wertung in diesem Block.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="2">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir sehr gut. 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="3">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir gut. 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="4">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir befriedigend. 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="5">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir in ausreichender Weise. 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="6">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir mangelhaft. 5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="7">
                    <p>Die inhaltliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir nur ungenügend. 6</p>
                </div>
            </div>



        <div id="headline">
            <p>Überschrift: Sprachliche Gestaltung - Wertung x2</p>
        </div>

            <div class="div_a">
                <div class="a" id="8">
                    <p>Keine Wertung in diesem Block.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="9">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir sehr gut. 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="10">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir gut. 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="11">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir befriedigend. 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="12">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir in ausreichender Weise. 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="13">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir mangelhaft. 5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="14">
                    <p>Die sprachliche Gestaltung der Überschrift gelang dir nur ungenügend. 6</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="headline">
            <p>Einleitung: Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen - Wertung x1</p>
        </div>

            <div class="div_a">
                <div class="a" id="15">
                    <p>Keine Wertung in diesem Block.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="16">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir sehr gut. 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="17">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir sehr gut. 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="18">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir befriedigend. 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="19">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir in ausreichender Weise. 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="20">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir mangelhaft. 5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="a" id="21">
                    <p>Die Vorstellung der Hauptpersonen gelang dir nur ungenügend. 6</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my JQuery approach - which causes ALL of the divs to toggle :(

```
  $('.a').on('click', function() {
     $('.a').not(this).toggle('slow')
 });
```

Thanks a lot in advance!
Lisa

Comment: RESOLVED! I just used the following code

Comment: $('.a').on('click', function() {
         $(this).siblings('.a').toggle('slow')
     });